# Expression and explanation of quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-chemistry

I am currently studying the textbook *Infrared and Raman Spectroscopy*, 2nd edition, by Peter Larkin. In a section entitled **Quantum Mechanical Harmonic Oscillator**, the author says the following:

> Fig. 2.6 shows the vibrational levels in a PE [potential energy] diagram for the quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator. In the case of the harmonic potential these states are equidistance and have energy levels $E$ given by
>
> $$E_i = (v_i + 1/2)h \nu \ \ \ \ v_i = 0, 1, 2, \dots$$
>
> Here $\nu$ is the classical vibrational frequency of the oscillator and $v$ is a quantum number that can only have integer values. This can only change by $\Delta v = \pm 1$ in a harmonic oscillator model, and thus a transition will be forbidden unless the initial states differ by one quantum of excitation. The so-called zero point energy occurs when $v = 0$ where $E = \dfrac{1}{2} h \nu$ and this vibrational energy cannot be removed from the molecule.
>
> [image]

I have two questions relating to this:

1. Throughout this text, it seems that the author is not a fan of commas, so I'm unsure if "the so-called zero point energy occurs when $v = 0$ where $E = \dfrac{1}{2} h \nu$[,] and this vibrational energy cannot be removed from the molecule", or whether the author meant it (and it is correct) as written. In other words, is the fact that this vibrational energy cannot be removed from the molecule a *requirement* for the zero-point energy to occur, which is what is meant as written, in the absence of the comma, or is $E = \dfrac{1}{2} h \nu$ the *only* requirement for the zero-point energy to occur, and the fact that "this vibrational energy cannot be removed from the molecule" is an afterthought, and *not* a requirement for the zero-point energy to occur, which would be the case *with* the comma?
2. Why does the expression for $E_i$ contain the $\dfrac{1}{2}$? It is not immediately clear why this expression would need to include this, so I'm curious as to the physical/mathematical reason for this.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify these two points.

Comment: the sentence with the comma is correct

Comment: @user2723984 Ahh, ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have a Harmonic oscillator with Hamiltonian
$$\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{m\omega^2x^2}{2},$$
then, by solving the Schrödinger equation, we obtain its energy states as
$$E_n = \hbar\omega(n+\frac{1}{2}), n = 0, 1, 2,...$$
We could remove $\frac{1}{2}$ by shifting the energy origin (and sometimes it is done), but note that $E=0$ is the minimal possible energy of the corresponding classical oscillator. So $\frac{1}{2}$ is kept to underscore this distinction, which is consistent, because the averages of $\langle x^2\rangle$, $\langle p^2\rangle$ remain different from zero.

Comment: I haven't studied Hamiltonians yet. So are you saying that the energy origin starts at $\dfrac{1}{2}$ in nature? Otherwise, why would we mathematically make it start at $\dfrac{1}{2}$, instead of making it start at $0$ (if it starts at $0$ in nature, that is)? That is confusing to me.

Comment: You understand the classical oscillator? It has potential energy $V(x)=\frac{kx^2}{2}$, and oscillation frequency $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$. The energy of such an oscillator is a sum of its kinetic and potential energies: $E=\frac{mv^2}{2} + \frac{kx^2}{2}$. The minimum of energy occurs when $x=0, v=0$, where we have $E=0$. For the quantum oscillator such thing is impossible: the position and velocity cannot be simultaneously zero, due to the uncertainty principle. So the *minimal energy of a quantum oscillator with the same potential* is $E=\hbar\omega/2$.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me.