The eigenvalues of quantum harmonic oscillator
Can someone explain to me what is the green curve in the graphical rapresentation of energy levels for a quantum harmonic oscillator? I've always encounter this type of photo and nobody explains what that curve actually is and represents.


It is supposed to represent the potential energy $\omega^2 x^2/2$ in the Hamiltonian $H= p^2/2 + \omega^2 x^2/2$.

@mikestone Please do no answer in comments.

@ZeroTheHero Please do no answer in comments.

Same figure e.g. here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/551642/226902

Usually, such plots show the potential energy of the system together with the location of the eigenvalues as a horizontal line at the correct energy.
For instance, the figure below shows the shape of the Morse potential (for some selected values of the parameters of this potential) in orange, together with its harmonic approximation (in light green), illustrating that the lowest levels of Morse have almost the same energy as the levels of a harmonic oscillator.

